# JQuery Month & Year Picker with Custom Text in Dropdown or Last Selected Month & Year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, web-frontend

I have a JQuery Month and Year picker and I'm trying to make the dropdowns of the month and year display a generic text or display the last selected month and year values. Right now it displays the latest month and date according to the range set.

I have tried using `beforeShow` but it doesn't work and `defaultDate` only accepts date values. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Datepicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #ui-datepicker-div{
            width: 20rem;
            left: 632px;
        }
        .ui-datepicker-calendar {
            display: none;
        }
        .datepicker{
            margin-top: 1rem;
            display: grid;
            justify-items: center;
        }
        select > option{
            background-color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
        }
        .ui-datepicker-prev{
            background: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .ui-datepicker-next{
            background: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button{
            color: white;
            background: black;
        }
        .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button:hover{
            color: white;
            background: rgb(234, 176, 0);
        }
        .monthYearPicker{
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            height: 2rem;
            width: 20rem;
        }
        .monthYearPara{
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="datepicker">
        <p class="monthYearPara">Pick Month & Year:</p>
        <input readonly name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" placeholder=" Date Picker " />
    </div>
<!-- REQUIRED FOR MONTH & YEAR PICKER -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                minDate: new Date(2020, 0),  // Year, Index of Month (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
                maxDate: new Date(2023, 3),  // Year, Index of Month (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
                dateFormat: 'MM yy'
            }).focus(function() {
                var thisCalendar = $(this);
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
                $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle doesn't load it properly for some reason, but the working copy can be viewed here:
**https://onecompiler.com/html/3z7zk6ang**

Edit:
By dropdowns, I intend to change the values of the highlighted fields:

[image: Dropdown Screenshot]